# Problem with displaying data from Firebase in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I am creating a small test app that should display data from the Firebase Realtime Database to Textview in Android Studio with a real-time on change method. However, nothing seems to happen and the text view remains empty.

Here is the code

```
type hepackage com.example.myapplication

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.getValue
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.ktx.initialize

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var database : DatabaseReference
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val backgroundColor = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvBackgroundColor2)
        val nonSelectedColor = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvNonSelectedColor2)
        val textColor = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTextColor2)
        val mainColor = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvMainColor2)
        val selectedColor = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvSelectedColor2)
        val progressColor = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvProgressColor2)
        val otherColor = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvOtherColor2)

        for (i in 1..5){
            val loc = "Paterns/Patern".plus(i.toString())
            Firebase.initialize(this)
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(loc)
            database.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    database.child(loc).get().addOnSuccessListener {

                        if (it.exists() && it.child("isSelected").value as Boolean){

                            backgroundColor.text = it.child("backgroundColor").value.toString()
                            nonSelectedColor.text = it.child("nonSelectedColor").value.toString()
                            textColor.text = it.child("textColor").value.toString()
                            mainColor.text = it.child("mainColor").value.toString()
                            selectedColor.text = it.child("selectedColor").value.toString()
                            progressColor.text = it.child("progressColor").value.toString()
                            otherColor.text = it.child("otherColor").value.toString()

                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Successfuly Read",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }.addOnFailureListener{
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    // Failed to read value
                    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is structure of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sECAP.png)

I took most of the code from a youtube tutorial where this method worked just fine.

Comment: dont use image to show your database structure. you can write your schema of database. and log data inside onDataChange function so that dataSnapshot are as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code comes from the fact that you're attaching a listener at every iteration of the loop, and you're also getting data from the `loc` location. I'm not sure why are you setting the data at each iteration, because you will end up having only the value of the last item displayed in the view. However, the code for reading the data can be simplified like this:

```
val paternsRef = Firebase.database.reference.child("Paterns")
paternsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        val snapshot = it.result
        for (paternSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
            val backgroundColor = paternSnapshot.child("backgroundColor").getValue(String::class.java)
            Log.d(TAG, "$backgroundColor")
            //Get the other values. 
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "${it.exception?.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

This code will print you the value of `backgroundColor` of each pattern in the logcat:

```
000000
0477bf
```

If you, however, need the read the data of a single item, for example, "Patern1", then please use the following line of code:

```
val paternOneRef = Firebase.database.reference.child("Paterns/Patern1")
paternOneRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        val snapshot = it.result
        val backgroundColor = snapshot.child("backgroundColor").getValue(String::class.java)
        Log.d(TAG, "$backgroundColor")
        //Get the other values. 
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "${it.exception?.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

This code will print you the value of `backgroundColor` of the first item in the logcat:

```
000000
```

Comment: Yes, I have figured it out, thank you for your help